# How to count number of records per day, matching a specific criteria

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure:

| ts | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-03 22:43:58.163000 UTC | success |
| 2023-08-03 06:12.797000 UTC | failure |
| 2023-08-02 20:42:14.960000 UTC | success |
| 2023-08-02 01:24:04.797000 UTC | success |

I want to count the number of successess per day, so

| day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-03 | 1 |
| 2023-08-02 | 2 |

I have the following statement:

`SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), count(status) FROM Responses WHERE status='success' GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY)`

Would this work?

The above returns a list but I am not sure if it is accurate (not super familiar with SQL and specifically GROUP BY operations.

Comment: it gives you the correct one, but you should ses a result, wehere only unique days are shown, and you can test the numbers by selecting single days and count them